# Discor.py. Можно ли выполнять команду каждый час?

Tags: python, python-3.x, discord, discord.py

Используются коги, пытался найти в документации подходящий класс под эту задачу, но безуспешно.
Создать фоновую задачу не выходит, самый рабочий метод был:

```py
import os
import discord
import asyncio

from discord.ext import tasks
from utils import default
from utils.data import Bot, HelpFormat

config = default.config()
print("Logging in...")

bot = Bot(
    command_prefix=config["prefix"], prefix=config["prefix"],
    owner_ids=config["owners"], command_attrs=dict(hidden=True), help_command=HelpFormat(),
    intents=discord.Intents(  # kwargs found at https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html?highlight=intents#discord.Intents
        guilds=True, members=True, messages=True, reactions=True, presences=True
    )
)

async def background_task():
      time = 5
      await asyncio.sleep(time)
      print('background_task are working')

for file in os.listdir("cogs"):
    if file.endswith(".py"):
        name = file[:-3]
        bot.load_extension(f"cogs.{name}")

try:
    bot.loop.create_task(background_task())
    bot.run(config["token"])
except Exception as e:
    print(f'Error when logging in: {e}')
```

Но этот код выполнял поставленную задачу 1 раз.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Так зацикли

```
async def background_task():
    while True:
        time = 5
        await asyncio.sleep(time)
        print('background_task are working')
```